# Line by line parsing of Perl Mechanize content

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

Creating perl scritps to auto download CSV's from various billers websites but I'm having problems taking the data from $mech->content() into something I can parse line by line for some reason. The content is a multi line CSV file,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize;
use IO::Socket::SSL qw();

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
...stuff...
my $data=$mech->content();
my (@lines)=split(/\n?\r/,$data);
print "lines=".@lines."\n---\n@lines\n---\n";
write_file("tmp.csv",$data);

for(my $i=0;$i<@lines;$i++){
    ...work that's done that depends on each 
    line being represented as an element of 
    an array... 
}
```

Originally I assigned $mech->content() directly to @lines, tried a few other things like $mech->content( raw => 1 ), as you see above I tried splitting it with \n or \r.
Browser shows the csv file as text/plain, Quirks mode, UTF-8
Running file tmp.csv shows it's ASCII text and is multiline.

What am I doing wrong, and what's that right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
my (@lines)=split(/\n?\r/,$data);
```

You have the newline regex backwards. It's `\r?\n`, but it's safer to write `\015?\012` for the literal characters because `\r` and `\n` can be different on some systems.

Your for loop can be better written as:

```
for my $line (@lines) {
```

However, you generally don't want to process entire files as an array. What you're doing can use a tremendous amount of memory. Instead it's better to first save it to disk and read the CSV file line by line.

```
use autodie;

$mech->get( $uri, ':content_file' => "test.csv" );

open my $fh, "test.csv";
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    ...
}
```

But don't do your own CSV parsing. It's much faster and less buggy to use [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS).

Comment: Thanks, now I feel silly. These shouldn't get big and using Net::Google::Spreadsheets::Spreadsheet for the larger file. Wanting to avoid unnecessary writes to Raspberry Pi SD. The parsing is reversing and removing duplicates. Thanks again!